# Time travel book - Character connected with "Staten"?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This was a young adult book/s. There were a good four or five books in the series. The books are pretty short as it's easy reading.

- The main character is a girl. She accidentally time travels and meets a boy. I think his name is **Staten** or his family runs a lot of things in Staten Island.
- I believe in one of the last ones at the beginning she time travels and ends up in a winter area, and she's in a yellow sundress.
- Her boyfriend that she time-travelled to meet was put into a mental institution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're describing the "[Time Travelers Quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Travelers_Quartet)" by Caroline B. Cooney.

> Annie Lockwood is watching her boyfriend, Sean, while he fixes his car, and she questions whether or not this is the right relationship for her. Then later, while she looks through the amazing Stratton Mansion she is wrenched from her time (approximately 1995) back 100 years into the past. In this past, she meets the inhabitants of the house, including a young man named **Strat [Lockwood Stratton]**. Murders happen in the house, and Annie soon falls in love with Strat, and she ends up going back and forth between the two time periods, But where will she end up? And with whom?

In the second book, Strat ends up in an insane asylum

> While in New York, she slips back one hundred years into the past, only to discover her one true love, Strat, was put into an insane asylum. He was put there because he insisted Annie was real, even though she mysteriously disappeared and everyone else decided to forget her existence

[image]

Comment: That's perfect thanks!